# Contour plot: ignored columns, wrong color-assignment, 1D-interpolation

Tags: pgfplots

This forum has often been of a great help for me, but i never posted myself. So please excuse me, if i won't stick to every formality here perfectly. I will do my best. I hope it's ok that i have 3 different questions on one plot.

I try to create a surface plot by means of `\addplots3[surf]` and a coordinate table of the form *x y z*. Whereas *x* is a more or less continous variable, *y* contains only 10 columns representing 10 different functions of *x*. *z* is nothing but an intensity which i want to display via a color map.

My source code is the following

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pgfplotstableread{carvon-contour.txt}\carvon

%data are of the form
%
%282.7  1   0.0007976728
%282.7  2   0.0007010106
%282.7  3   0.0002862722
%282.7  4   0.0010733289
%282.7  5   0.0004453488
%282.7  6   0.0005347549
%282.7  7   0.0006696946
%282.7  8   0.0008733782
%282.7  9   0.0005243997
%282.7  10  0.0005450571
%282.740201005  1   0.0008267864
%282.740201005  2   0.0007236548
%282.740201005  3   0.0002901354
%282.740201005  4   0.0011133781
%282.740201005  5   0.0004554805
%282.740201005  6   0.0005512185
%282.740201005  7   0.0006887026
%282.740201005  8   0.000905994
%282.740201005  9   0.0005406747
%282.740201005  10  0.0005593566
%...

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [
        view={0}{90},
        colormap/bluered,
        minor x tick num=3,         
        xmin=283.8,
        xmax=289.3,
        minor y tick num=0,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=11,
        colorbar
  ]
    \addplot3[surf, mesh/cols=10, shader=flat] table {\carvon};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Whereas the output is this:

[image]

As one can see the plot displays only 9 of 10 columns. Can someone see a reason for that?

Now, the colormap ranges from 0 to about 0.28 just as the data do, but somehow the colors of the plot only reach to about 0.16 (yellow). Does pgfplots perform kind of a binning so that peak values of greater than 0.2 are averaged to lower values? Or did i miss something else? And most important: how to get rid of it?

Last but not least: As i said before, the *x*-axis is continious, whearas *y* is not. Is there a way of interpolating the data along the x-axis in order to obtain a smoother curve, but not along the y-axis at the same time? `shader=interp` interpolates in both directions.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Ok, all 3 issues had the same origin. Of course, pgfplots uses 2 values along the y-axis for one polygon. One row within the plot belongs to 2 neighbouring columns of my data. This has different effects: 1.

Comment: i am sorry, i sent my comment accidentally and wasn't fast enough with editing it. here is what i intended to write: "This has different effects: 1. there are just 9 pairs, (1 and 2, 2 and 3, ..., 9 and 10); 2. the color for one row arises from the average of both columns (don't mix up my column and row here. by row i mean the graph and by column my data); 3. i created 2 columns per row now (at 0.5 and 1.5 for the former column 1...) and every row is its own plot. now i can use shader=interp as well. Thanks for reading this nonetheless"

Comment: I think it would be good if you would post your answer such that it is of use to others. Or are there open issues?